# Why is the Discrete Fourier series a sum from $0$ to $N - 1$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, derivation-of-formulae, derivations

I want to derive the Discrete Fourier series:
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} X_k e^{i2\pi xk}$$
from the Continuous Fourier Series formula:
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} X_k e^{i2\pi xk}$$

additionally I've heard that if the signal is real then the fourier coefficients are symmetrical and hence the discrete fourier series only sums from  0 to N - 1?
can somebody explain how the first equation is derived from the second and what role the coefficient symmetry plays into all of this? thank in advance

Comment: I believe this [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_series#Definition) provides insight.

Comment: As a discrete signal, it provides the signal values at discrete sampling moments only, does not provide any information of the signal value between sampling moments. that is, its time resolution of the signal is limited. Correspondingly, it contains information about the frequency components between $\pm f_s/2\  Hz$ only, nothing beyond, where $f_s$ is the sampling frequency. For continuous signal $x(t)$, it provides signal values continuously with infinitely fine resolution. Thus, it covers infinitely wide frequency range (as long as it really has infinitely high frequency components).